# Android Single Task Activity Flag Activity A > Activity B > Activity B Routers Back Problem

Tags: android, android-intent

We are using deeplink and the navigation directions is like on the above. So the Activity A (Single Task) starts Activity B then,Activity A is navigate again Activity B with New Intent from Deeplink. However when we after back two of same Activity B (the last one) is shown in the screen two times. How we prevent two different of Activity B instances while we onBackPressed.

Comment: Make B also Single Task. So only 1 instance of B will be created.

Comment: But I want B two instances. This is the problem for me.

Comment: Any specific reason for 2 instances?

Comment: the reason of activity A is the single task, after first created Activity B then A create again B from deeplink and NewIntent, but there are no two instances. Activity B is overriding itself. However I don't want. While onBackPressed just one B activity on the screen two time. The before state is lost.

Comment: Please correct if I misunderstood your problem.  
You have Activity A ( single Task) which launches B.  Now when you receive deep-link, A opens B again.


A is a single task so only 1 instance of A will created. 
and B will be created twice.

Making B also as single task and handle onNewIntent() method.

Comment: On the first scenario, I ve tried A launches first B then the deeplink active so that A launches second B but I want to while onBack A>firstB>secondB however on this scenario after second B launced just A comes front. Then I try second scenario. This is like that A launches first B then deeplink comes with params (remember the first B context) then first B launch second B. However on this scenario A>secondB>secondB it comes while onBack but I want A>firstB>secondB.